# The async.queue never drains?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, queue

I am trying to query a flight api with my async queue in node but it appears as my queue never "drains" (simply run the drain method). [I am using this library](http://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#.queue).

It runs every request just fine but then it just stops there and the content in the drain function never executes.

```
let flights = [];
let q = async.queue(function (airline, callback) {
  const flight_search_url = 'http://someflightapi.com/search/' + airline.code + '?date=' + date + '&from=' + originAirportCode + '&to=' + destinationAirportCode;
  request(flight_search_url, function(error, response, body) {
    if (error) {
      return callback(error);
    }
    if (res.statusCode !== 200) {
      return callback(res.statusCode);
    }
    console.log(airline.code);
    flights.push(JSON.parse(body));
    callback();
  });
}, 10);

q.drain(function(error) {
  if (error) {
    res.json({
      error: "There was an error while calculating flights",
      destinationAirportCode: destinationAirportCode,
      originAirportCode: originAirportCode,
      possibleOrigins: possibleOrigins,
      possibleDestinations: possibleDestinations,
      flights: flights
    });
  } else {
    res.json(flights);
  }
});

q.push(airlines);
```

Comment: did you find a solution to your/this issue?

Comment: @gdibble sorry, I used promises instead to solve my issue.

Comment: It's ok, thanks; I also solved my problem another way.